# Scrapy parse list of urls, open one by one and parse additional data

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to parse a site, an e-store. I parse a page with products, which are loaded with ajax, get urls of these products,and then parse additional info of each product following these parced urls.

My script gets the list of first 4 items on the page, their urls, makes the request, parses add info, but then not returning into the loop and so spider closes.

Could somebody help me in solving this? I'm pretty new to this kind of stuff, and ask here when totally stuck.

Here is my code:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy_sokos.items import SokosItem


class SokosSpider(Spider):
    name = "sokos"
    allowed_domains = ["sokos.fi"]
    base_url = "http://www.sokos.fi/fi/SearchDisplay?searchTermScope=&searchType=&filterTerm=&orderBy=8&maxPrice=&showResultsPage=true&beginIndex=%s&langId=-11&sType=SimpleSearch&metaData=&pageSize=4&manufacturer=&resultCatEntryType=&catalogId=10051&pageView=image&searchTerm=&minPrice=&urlLangId=-11&categoryId=295401&storeId=10151"
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.sokos.fi/fi/SearchDisplay?searchTermScope=&searchType=&filterTerm=&orderBy=8&maxPrice=&showResultsPage=true&beginIndex=0&langId=-11&sType=SimpleSearch&metaData=&pageSize=4&manufacturer=&resultCatEntryType=&catalogId=10051&pageView=image&searchTerm=&minPrice=&urlLangId=-11&categoryId=295401&storeId=10151",
    ]

    for i in range(0, 8, 4):
        start_urls.append((base_url) % str(i))


    def parse(self, response):
        products = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="product-listing product-grid"]/article[@class="product product-thumbnail"]')
        for product in products:
            item = SokosItem()
            item['url'] = product.xpath('//div[@class="content"]/a[@class="image"]/@href').extract()[0]

            yield Request(url = item['url'], meta = {'item': item}, callback=self.parse_additional_info) 

    def parse_additional_info(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['name'] = Selector(response).xpath('//h1[@class="productTitle"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item['description'] = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@id="kuvaus"]/p/text()').extract()[0]
        euro = Selector(response).xpath('//strong[@class="special-price"]/span[@class="euros"]/text()').extract()[0]
        cent = Selector(response).xpath('//strong[@class="special-price"]/span[@class="cents"]/text()').extract()[0]
        item['price'] = '.'.join(euro + cent)
        item['number'] = Selector(response).xpath('//@data-productid').extract()[0]
        yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AJAX requests you are simulating are caught by the Scrapy "duplicate url filter".

Set `dont_filter` to `True` when yielding a `Request`:

```
yield Request(url=item['url'], 
              meta={'item': item},    
              callback=self.parse_additional_info, 
              dont_filter=True)
```

Comment: but i still can't make it work properly. as i try in the shell, at first it returns a list of urls (four links). then, substituting each link in Request, parse add data from each page. i tried Request(url=item['url'][0], etc. ) but no changes. =0

Comment: @deniskrishna well, it definitely should make a difference. It worked for me, meaning that now I see multiple URLs issued for the additional info. There are also some exceptions but this is not a part of the question. Thanks.